# Context menu icon not appearing in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I am making a test extension but the item is not appearing in context menu. What is wrong here?

My manifest file

```
{
 "name": "Colour",
 "version": "1.0.1",
 "description": "Colour the background on right clicking image.",
 "offline_enabled": true,
 "permissions" : [
 "contextMenus",
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
 ],
 "background_page":"background.html"
}
```

My background.html contains this script

```
function getColour(info, tab){
  document.body.style.background="#456";
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "type":"normal",
  "title":"Colour page",
  "contexts":["image"],
  "onclick":getColour()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference to the `getColour` function has to be passed. It should **not** [be invoked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions):

```
function getColour(info, tab){
    document.body.style.background="#456";
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "type": "normal",
    "title": "Colour page",
    "contexts": ["image"],
    "onclick": getColour // <--- Removed ()
});
```

**Previously**, your code would work in this way:

1. `getColour()` -  Calls `getColour`.
2. There is no `return` statement in the function, so it returns [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).
3. `chrome.contextMenu.create({ ... "onclick": undefined });` - **No event handler**!

Comment: @Shikhar Sharma  If you have still have problems understanding the difference between invoking/calling/executing a function and referencing one (like for a callback) then just say so and Ill try and write an answer explaining it.  I myself had quite a bit of a problem getting it in the beginning (if your out there somewhere Waha, thank you ;))

Comment: @PAEz It's not difficult: When a function name is postfixed by two parentheses, eg `name()`, the function is **invoked**. When these are left out, a **reference to the function is passed,** eg `name`

Comment: I get that now, but it took me making the mistake 3 times and having Waha explain it to me before I really got it.... especially when it came to the idea of callbacks.

Comment: @RobW - Thanks. I removed the () and i now understand the difference between invoking and referencing. The item now appears in the context menu. But on clicking on it nothing happens - background color of the tab containing the image i right-clicked still remains the same.

Comment: @ShikharSharma `document` refers to the background page. You have to populate the body of `getColour` with [`chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:'document.body.style.background="#456";'});`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)